# Detect support for Uint8Array and other new objects without spawning errors or warnings

Tags: javascript

How do I detect support for `new Uint8Array()` and other `new [object]` declarations without triggering errors in older versions of browsers that don't support them?

I can't have any errors or warnings from support detection and no frameworks or libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global methods are also properties of the `window` so you can do things like:

```
if (window.Uint8Array && typeof window.Uint8Array === 'function')
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying the `in` operator without success. I'll accept it once the timer expires. Thanks!

Comment: Ah... I somehow had deleted the `U` at `[0]`. >__>